# Two Macs and One Apple ID (purchases on App Store)

Tags: ios-appstore, apple-id, license

I have a Macbook Air mid 2012 model and now I'm thinking about buying a Mac Mini or a iMac so that I can have my Macbook Air for when I'm on the road, and the Mini or iMac stationed at home all the time. For my setup now, I have a external display for my Air when I'm working at home, and I'm getting kinda tired of disconnecting and connecting the external display, mouse, and keyboard every day.

But then I thought about, how about all my purchases on App Store (OS X apps), are they automatically cleared to be installed on my new machine, while I still have them on my Macbook Air or is there going to be some kinda conflict with license?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have up to ten devices (any combination of iOS devices or Macs) associated with one Apple ID; that means you could install the same software from the App Store on up to ten Macs. If one of them breaks or you sell one, you can de-authorize it, so your total goes down again.

For details on authorizing that go beyond your initial question (including some time limits for changing authorization), see http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4627?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

Answer (score 3):

This question can only really be answered on a per app level (The End User License Agreement (EULA) will specify how many machines an application can be installed on), but in general I have a MacBook Pro, My wife has a Macbook Air and we have a media center mac mini and I install all my apps on all of them without an issue, but we share a single Apple ID for all app store purchases, since apple has restrictions on using multiple Apple IDs on a single machine.

Developers seem to have a more sane point of view on mac (excluding Adobe or other graphics packages) than on windows, so I haven't had an issue.

Comment: Okay, like for example my anti-virus its 3 license I have for that I think.
But nice to hear that it's all good with app store apps.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly it.